# How can we access to a multidimensional array

Tags: java

How can we access to a multiple dimension array without even knowing it !
For example :

```
Object[][] inputs = { new Object[] { "a", "ab", "abc" },
            new Object[] { "abc", "ab", "a" },
            new Object[] { "big", new Object[] { "ab", "a", }, "t" },
            new Object[] { "big", new Object[] { "ab", "a", new Object[] { "superbig", "a" } }, "tiny" },
            new Object[] { 123, 23123123, "a" },
            new Object[] { null, new Object[] {}, "a" } };
```

I thought it was 2 dimensional but it's not 2 (which i'm not happy with that syntax of java) and i need to get all the information of the inputs array object.
How am i suppose to solve this ? Is there any method for transforming a multidimensional array into one dimension ?

P.S.: The Output should be { abc, abc, big,superbig,23123123,a} (it's the biggest string of each line of the object !)

Comment: Let's assume that you do manage to access the `arrays` without knowing it. What would you like to do with them? Print their contents?

Comment: probably something like arrayutils "flatten" - check out commons lib.

Comment: I wanted particularly get the longest String of each position of the first dimension !
For example : the Output should be { abc, abc, big,superbig,23123123,a}

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how you can use method  toSingleDimension to find longest strings, output should be now as you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily flatten any-dimensional array to single dimension, at runtime, using reflection. You can use it to compute find longest strings as you required with your edit.

Working runnable example program:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Program {

    private static Object[] toSingleDimension(Object array) {
        ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        toSingleDimensionRecursive(arrayList, array);
        return arrayList.toArray();
    }

    private static void toSingleDimensionRecursive(ArrayList<Object> output, Object object) {
        if (object == null) {
            output.add(null);
        } else if (!object.getClass().isArray()) {
            output.add(object);
        } else {
            int length = Array.getLength(object);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                Object value = Array.get(object, i);
                toSingleDimensionRecursive(output, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String findLongestString(Object[] array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String result = null;
        for (Object object : array) {
            if (object != null) {
                String text = object.toString();
                if (result == null) {
                    result = text;
                } else if (text != null && text.length() > result.length()) {
                    result = text;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[][] inputs = {new Object[]{"a", "ab", "abc"},
            new Object[]{"abc", "ab", "a"},
            new Object[]{"big", new Object[]{"ab", "a",}, "t"},
            new Object[]{"big", new Object[]{"ab", "a", new Object[]{"superbig", "a"}}, "tiny"},
            new Object[]{123, 23123123, "a"},
            new Object[]{null, new Object[]{}, "a"}};

//      Object[] data = toSingleDimension(inputs);
//      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(data));

        ArrayList<String> longestStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object input : inputs) {
            Object[] array = toSingleDimension(input);
            String longest = findLongestString(array);
            if (longest != null) {
                longestStrings.add(longest);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Longest strings of arrays: " + longestStrings);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Longest strings of arrays: [abc, abc, big, superbig, 23123123, a]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion to achieve this easily.

```
public List<Object> convert(Object input) {
    List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    if (input instanceof Object[]) {
        for (Object object : (Object[]) input) {
            objectList.addAll(convert(object)); // Instead of addAll here, just add max element. I am a little too lazy to implement that...:)
        }
    } else {
        objectList.add(input);
    }
    return objectList;
}
```

Comment: Smart decision to use an `ArrayList`. +1. That being said, this will only work if the inner arrays are all `Object` arrays. Not sure if that would always be the case.

Comment: @Chetan I thought any array is an Object array.. no?? Ofcourse, if we have `Collections` in place of arrays it wouldn't work.

Comment: `int[]` is not an object array, for example.

Comment: @AbishekManoharan My bad. I meant if all inner objects are references of type `array`. This should work for all types of inner arrays including primitives.

Comment: Ahh... Yes, if a primitive array is specifically created eg with new int[]{}, then it wouldn't work...